# php csv import looping and inserting

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file below the first row is the header.

I want to read all the rows from CSV and insert each columns from csv  as each row in database table.

In the table the order will be as shown below

```
-------
TABLE
-------
ID  Value
---------------
1    25-10-2013
2    12:53:35
3    test1
4    india
5    asia
6   26-10-2013
7   2:53:40
8   test2
9   uk
10   europe
11   27-10-2013
12   23:16:20
13   test3
14   dubai
15   asia
```

i tried using the belwo code

```
<?php
  $row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            "insert statement here ""
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the ID column is auto increment, your query should be

```
INSERT table(value) 
VALUES ('$data[$c]');
```

if isn´t autoincrement,

```
INSERT table(id,value) 
VALUES ('$row','$data[$c]');
```

with mysql, is

```
$loadsql = "INSERT table(value) 
VALUES ('$data[$c]');";
mysql_query($loadsql) or die(mysql_error());
```

i hope this can help you.